# Get/Update a component field from event code

Tags: 2011, event-system

I am working on event code 2011. I want to access a component attached to the page and update a field in that component.  The component has two fields (Body and BodyImagePublish), both are text field.   I know the code to read the component and acess its field but i don't know why the field shows null even if the component's [Body] field has the value(value is basically a xml)

The code is as below

```
      //Getting the component attached to this page
            page2 = (Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page)publication.GetObject(uRI);
            //Getting the component as i want to read the [Body] field. Body has the xml  
            compToUpdate = page2.ComponentPresentations[0].Component;
            //I checked in the log generated by below statement that i am getting the tcm id of the component which has the values
            EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("comtoUpdate string: " + compToUpdate.ToString());
            //But the below condition does not satisfy, i opened the component and am sure that there is value in the body field
            if (compToUpdate.Content["Body"].Value != null)
            {
                //this condition does not  get satisfied which means that the component is null
            }
            //I also tried the below code from TOM.NET API chm file, but it throws error
            ItemFields contentFields = new ItemFields(compToUpdate.Content, compToUpdate.Schema);
            TextField myTextField = (TextField)contentFields["Body"];
            string myTextFieldValue = myTextField.Value;
            EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("comtoUpdate body field: " + myTextFieldValue);
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the value of compToUpdate.Content?  It should return an XML document.

Comment: Perhaps the XML name of the field is something other than "Body"?

Comment: @robrtc - The value of content comes as System.Xml.XmlElement and comptoUpdate.Metadata comes as blank.

Comment: @Nickoli- The name of the field is Body only.

Comment: @robrtc - I modified the code to compToUpdate.Content.InnerXml.ToString() and i was able to get the xml I m looking for but i dont know why the content comes as  **<Body xmlns="uuid:16075D15-21EF-6D0-9059-868D714CA6E6">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;images&gt;&lt;image&gt;         &lt;title&gt;Advanced ship system designs&lt;/title&gt;          &lt;thumbnail&gt;/Imagescasestudy_advanced_ship_design_tcm92-45625.jpg&lt;/thumbnail&gt;          &lt;previewimage&gt;/Images/casestudy_advanced_ship_design_tcm92-45625.jpg&lt;/previewimage&gt;**

Comment: Please share the source of your component in question - Open the component, go to the source tab and paste the component xml here. I doubt if the root element xml name of the schema of the component is also Body and it might be conflicting with the xml name of the field

Comment: @pankaj- the source is **<Content xmlns="uuid:16075D15-21EF-46D0-9059-868D714CA6E6"><Body>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;images&gt;&lt;image&gt;&lt;title&gt&lt;/images&gt;</Body></Content>**  I have removed some nodes as the character lenght exceeded

Comment: And you may want to try using XHtmlField instead of TextField.

Comment: @Nuno - How will i update the component with my modified xml. I am reading a component, making a xml node and then i am appending the new xml node to the XML which the component has in its body field. So how will I update the component body field with my newly appended xml. I mean  'compToUpdate.Content["Body"].Value = strXML;' it worked in Tridion 2009, but i dont think it will work in 2011.

Comment: No, indeed. You need to do Component.Content = contentFields.ToXml() after all your changes. Content is a "disconnected" collection

Answer (score 3):

answering the last comment to Nuno:

you can try below code, can adjust accordingly for checkout/checkin of the component. I havn't tested it so adjustments could be needed.

```
XDocument doc;
XElement xmlData;

string fieldName = "Body";
string fieldValue = "New Body Value";
doc = XDocument.Parse(compToUpdate.Content.OuterXml);
xmlData = doc.Root;
var newDoc = new XmlDocument();
XNamespace ns = xmlData.GetDefaultNamespace();
if (xmlData.Descendants(ns + fieldName).Count() > 0)
{
    xmlData.Descendants(ns + fieldName).SingleOrDefault().Value = fieldValue;

    newDoc.LoadXml(doc.ToString());
    compToUpdate.Content = newDoc.DocumentElement;
}

compToUpdate.Save();
```

**EDIT by Nuno**

Or you could acheve the same with the ItemFields class:

```
ItemFields content = new ItemFields(compToUpdate.Content, compToUpdate.Schema);
XhtmlField body = (XhtmlField) content["Body"];
body.Value = "some new value";
compToUpdate.Content = content.ToXml();
```

Since this is in an Event, I would not call Save(), and instead just modify the component in the `Initiated` phase and let Tridion do the save as normal.